# How to authenticate a git clone with gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a question is it possible to let someone authenticate when cloning your source code. I know you can set your repo to private but if someone knows the https address of your repo they can still git clone it without authentication except of having a gitlab or github user account. I think this is a weird approach because this is not a safe method of storing source code.you want  only let people clone this code that have permission to do so, not people that saw your https address and thought it would be fun to clone your code base.

Comment: *you can set your repo to private but if someone knows the https address of your repo they can still git clone it without authentication* That's not true. If the repo is private you can publish its URL for the entire world and nobody can clone it until you authorize them.

Comment: If the repo is private, even if they know the URL it should not be possible to clone it.

Comment: _if someone knows the https address of your repo they can still git clone it without authentication_ Why do you think this, and how did you test it? Did you happen to test it on the machine of someone who was already authenticated with an SSH key to a GitLab account with access to the repository?

Comment: I tested with a account that has access and a account that doesn't has access but both just clone the repo.

Answer (score 0):

If the repo is indeed private, the user need to be authenticated (either via email/password login or SSH key). Can you check your repo settings? There is no way for a private repo to get cloned without any credentials.

Comment: The repo is set to visibility private in a local gitlab sever.But when a cloning with a ssh key that is not a member of the repo the repo is still cloned what am i doing wrong here?